# How to export two DataTables in just one PDF file

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, datatables

I'm currently using DataTables to draw tables in a webpage. I have a table which is not hidden and users can view it without problems. On the other hand, I have a hidden table which has to be exported with the not hidden table at same time.

I want to be able to **click on "Export PDF" in the not hidden table and generate a PDF file with both tables**, the hidden and the not hidden table.

Could someone help me? I'm a little confused about how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I havn't tried this but you could attempt to simply trigger the second button from the first.

```
$("#foo .buttons-pdf").on("click", function() {
  $("#bar .buttons-pdf").trigger("click");
});
```

The second table will still need to be available in the DOM.

Comment: This could be an option, but both tables have similarly content, so I would like to print them into a single PDF file. If I don't found a nice solution for this, I think your solution would be the best.

Answer (score 1):

If you have identical tables it is dead easy. Simply have a third (or fourth etc) hidden table you only use for export purposes. When your "PDF" button is clicked follow these steps :

1. Beforehand, set the `*_wrapper` container to `display: none;` so the user never sees flicker or garbage on the screen
2. Use the API to collect data from all tables and merge them
3. Initialise the hidden export table and use the merged data as `data` source
4. Trigger the PDF export programmatically
5. Clean up the hidden export table so no conflicts occurs when the user tries to export a second time

===

```
$('#example').DataTable({ });
$('#example2').DataTable({ });

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var data = $('#example').DataTable().table().data();
  $.merge( data, $('#example2').DataTable().table().data() );
  $('#export-table').DataTable({
    dom: 'B',
    data: data,
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'pdfHtml5'
    }],
    drawCallback: function() {
      $('#export-table_wrapper .buttons-pdf').click()
       setTimeout(function() {
          $('#export-table').DataTable().destroy(false);
       }, 200)
    }
  })
})
```

Here is a demo with one visible table, one hidden table and a third table which takes care of the export -> **https://jsfiddle.net/u20x4be0/**

Comment: that's a nice solution!

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this if you want to export multiple different tables to a single pdf? For example say the tables all have the same header but each table is it's own entity (in my specific case the headers are the days of the week and each table represents a different employee, and I would like to keep the tables separate)

Comment: @NicLovin, phew, years since I have used DataTables. I am retired and no longer programmer. Just programming for fun, once in a while. You could ask a new question and use the answer above as reference, or copy paste the code as "what have I tried" in the question. But I can see the use of setTimeout should be eliminated, this is oldschool coding. I believe pdfmake today have a promise you can respond to, but this is not an answer to your question, just a comment to the old less safe coding style I apparently were using, or suggesting.

Comment: @davidkonrad okay I will look into that, thank you for the response!