# Two Datatables into a PDF file using one button - javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, button, datatable, datatables

I'm working with a database to generate graphs using an Input (to search info from database) and Output (to return info) page. When I search something, it returns two Datatables: outline and nodes, and each table has a PDF button to export data. However, I need a button to export both Datatables in just one PDF. I've already tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302673/how-to-export-two-datatables-in-just-one-pdf-file), but didn't work and I really don't know what to do; [what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKSm0.png) x [what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5riK.png).

Could someone help me?

Comment: Hi Please see how to best ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.