# jQuery Datatable extend print button to work for multiple tables on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've `1 to n` tables in a HTML page and want to print all of them in one flow.
jQuery Datatables delivers a "build-in" print button but this only works for the assigned table.
However, there must be some logic behind to collect all the data from the rows and print them.

Is it possible to extend this logic to work for several tables on the same page?

I've created this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6L34ph1w/2/) as a playground.

This is the build in print button logic:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'print'
    ]
} );
```

Those 2 minified js are needed to make the button work:
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js

Comment: You need to create your own custom function for this. I would start here https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.action

Comment: Can you create a snippet with an example that you have difficulty in making it working?

Comment: @LajosArpad - in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6L34ph1w/2/ I've created 2 tables, where the print button works in each one of them, but I don't know where to start when trying to print both tables at once.

Comment: I'm not an expert with jQuery datatables, but to me it seems that the creation of a wrapper DataTable of two rows, each row being a DataTable of its own and then having a print of the wrapper DataTable would do a print all. Since I do not know the limitations of Datatable, this certainly seems to be a direction you may want to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Print Multiple Tables in Multiple Pages**

You can make the "Print All" button call a function that will call each table's "Print" button.

So, using your fiddle elemets' ids, define `printAll`:

```
function printAll() {
    $('#example_wrapper .buttons-print').click();   
    $('#example2_wrapper .buttons-print').click();
}
```

... which will be called on-click:

```
$('#print-all').click(printAll);
```

[Full fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/uvmnc4hz/).

Do note, however, that this will open two different pages for print.

**Print Multiple Tables in Single Page**

If you want the  print to happen in a single page, you'll need to use some customization, by following these steps:

1. Use the `customize` option for each of your "Print" buttons.
2. On each of them, take the print-view table html from the opened print window into some global variable, and immediately close the print window.
3. On a `printAll` function:
   a. Call both button's click handlers to make them append their html to the global variable
   b. Then, open a new window of your own with the aggregated htmls, and don't forget to add the DataTables CSS.
   c. Wait shortly to let the opened window finish loading, and then call `print`.

[Full fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/b9s370f6/), but for completeness I'll put the final js code in the following snippet:

- Note: you can customize the print page anyway you like, just add html elements into the print window body. Please advise the links attached below.

```js
var all = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
              extend: 'print',
                customize: function (win) {
                all += $(win.document.body).find('table')[0].outerHTML;
                win.close();
                },
            }
        ]
    } );
  $('#example2').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
              extend: 'print',
                customize: function (win) {
                all += $(win.document.body).find('table')[0].outerHTML;
                win.close();
                },
            }
        ]
    } );
    $('#print-all').click(printAll);
});

function printAll() {
    $('#example_wrapper .buttons-print').click();   
  $('#example2_wrapper .buttons-print').click();
  var win = window.open("about:blank", "Print View");
  win.document.write(
    '<html>\
        <head>\
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">\
            </head>\
      <body></body>\
      </html>');
  win.document.close();
  $(win.document.body).append(all);
  setTimeout(function () { win.print(); }, 1000);
}
```

Further reading:

1. [How to get all stylesheets into the new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758288/open-a-new-javascript-window-open-along-with-its-css-styling).
2. [How to merge both tables into a single one for printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302673/how-to-export-two-datatables-in-just-one-pdf-file)
3. [DataTables' `print` documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/button/print)

Comment: Thanks - almost perfect.
The only thing to mention is, that it does not automatically starts the printers overview but the build in print button does. Is it possible to do that to?

Comment: @toffler, yap, I added the relevant code to the fiddle and the code snippet.